# RestClient::Conflict: 409 Conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orientdb, rest-client

I am getting this error when executing a function in my rails app through rails console. Primary database is OrientDB. And this fucntion is deleting edges in OrientDB in a loop.

```
RestClient::Conflict: 409 Conflict
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:74:in `return!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:495:in `process_result'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:421:in `block in transmit'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:877:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:413:in `transmit'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/resource.rb:67:in `post'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/active-orient-fdae334715ca/lib/rest/operations.rb:113:in `execute'
    from /home/ubuntu/rails-project/config/initializers/string.rb:27:in `run_active_orient'
```

First thing is I am not able to get which application generates this error. Is it **RestClient by rails** or **active-orient gem** (active-orient is the ORM used to access OrientDB in rails) or **orientDB-server**. The function seems to generate error at different steps every-time I run it. Also there is no error log on the orientDB server log screen.

Can anyone please help me with this error or help me understand what leads to the generation of the error.

Comment: From what I've understand from a Fast&Furious reading, rest-client, isn't intended to be used *inside* rails.

Comment: I think this is their by default. Moreover OrientDB responds in a restful way.

Answer (score 0):

You submitted a query via »execute«, which is transmitted through a POST-request. The requests are logged at the debug-level.

```
111       begin
112         logger.debug{ batch[:operations].map{|y|y[:command]}.join("; ") }
113         response = @res["/batch/#{ActiveOrient.database}"].post batch.to_json
114       rescue ...
```

Can you please provide a short test case and open an issue at github?
And include the output of the logger?